# Converting MGRS to Lat/Lon or UTM

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, latitude-longitude, utm, mgrs

How can I convert [Military Grid Reference System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_grid_reference_system) (MGRS) to lat/lon or UTM?

Answer (score 8):

I had to write code to convert MGRS to LL last year, however, I am unable to post the code. What I can post though are the two main resources I utilized while writing the code:

[US Military Grid Reference System description, published by NGA](http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/publications/tm8358.1/tr83581b.html#ZZ26) and the related [Appendix](http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/publications/tm8358.1/tr83581f.html) and an [Online MGRS to LL Converter](http://www.andrewlesley.freeserve.co.uk/gps/convertr/UTM-MGRS.html) to check your results as you are coding.

There is also [GeographicLib](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/), an open-source library that has code for MGRS conversions and is licensed under MIT. You'll need to look at the [GeographicLib::MGRS class](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/classGeographicLib_1_1MGRS.html), and the [MGRS.hpp](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/MGRS_8hpp_source.html) and [MGRS.cpp](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/MGRS_8cpp_source.html) files if you need to look at the code.

If you can elaborate more on whether you are looking for code, a library, or a utility to convert one or more coordinates, you'll get better answers.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Basically I am looking for some formula/code to convert MGRS to lat long or UTM. I am working with Silverlight API and I want to locate the point based on MGRS input.

Comment: My suggestion then is to look at GeographicLib and either compile the code as a DLL and use the DLL + PInvoke to access the methods from C#, or convert the relevant C++ code to C# (2nd option would be my preferred route).  Of course, assuming your project is compatible with a MIT style license.

Answer (score 3):

If someone needs this in JavaScript...

Probably worth linking to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/25669/5372), which includes a link to a GPL'd (unfortunately; LGPL would have been more universally useful) [JavaScript lib](http://www.koders.com/javascript/fid8BFB11FBBD0AEE3514D27417DC02B99602B01837.aspx?s=sha1) that'll do this.

I should probably add that the library is, more accurately, USNG, which is apparently very closely related to MGRS [but not exactly the same](http://www.amerisurv.com/PDF/TheAmericanSurveyor_USNationalGrid-Cavell_June2005.pdf).

> When referenced to NAD 83 or WGS 84, USNG values are equivalent to
> Military Grid Reference System (MGRS) values. The difference in these
> two systems is that USNG referenced to NAD27 uses the MGRS WGS 84
> scheme of 100,000m Square Identifications...

(from [the above link to *The American Surveyor*](http://www.amerisurv.com/PDF/TheAmericanSurveyor_USNationalGrid-Cavell_June2005.pdf))

It looks like OpenLayers lets you do it as well -- an example of it in a production environment (with an MIT-flavor license) <strike>can be found here</strike>.

That link is now (Mar 2023) dead and is not archived at archived.org. This project may be a decent replacement and is also MIT licensed.:

https://github.com/codice/usng.js/

Answer (score 3):

GDAL has a silent implementation of MGRS.

You can find the source code here:

https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/frmts/nitf/mgrs.c

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice online coordinates converter for WGS84, UTM, CH1903, UTMREF(MGRS), Gauß-Krüger, NAC, W3W: https://coordinates-converter.com/en/

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Python to convert MGRS to lat/long and vice versa. Using the library [`pyproj`](https://pypi.org/project/pyproj/) you can convert a given MGRS tile (say, WGS84) as follows:

```py
import pyproj

geod = pyproj.Geod(ellps='WGS84')

lat_min, lon_min = mgrs_object.toLatLon(mgrs_id)

x_var = geod.line_length([lon_min, lon_min], [lat_min, lat_min + 1])
y_var = geod.line_length([lon_min, lon_min + 1], [lat_min, lat_min])

lat_max = lat_min + mgrs_tile_edge_size / x_var
lon_max = lon_min + mgrs_tile_edge_size / y_var
```

`lat_min`, `lon_min`, `lat_max`, `lon_max` then give the corners of the tile in lon/lat coordinates.

For more background information you can have a look at this [blog post](https://dida.do/blog/understanding-mgrs-coordinates).

Comment: The mgrs Python module is needed in order to convert to/from MGRS coordinates, not the pyproj module.