# How can I convert MGRS using gdaltransform?

Tags: gdal

I'm using [gdaltransform](http://www.gdal.org/gdaltransform.html) to convert coordinates.

What's the best way to convert MGRS using [gdaltransform](http://www.gdal.org/gdaltransform.html) given that it doesn't have an EPSG code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert MGRS to Lat/Long or UTM?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15373/how-to-convert-mgrs-to-lat-long-or-utm)

Answer (score 1):

I have written a Python MGRS library to convert back and forth to lat/long, which you can then reproject as necessary.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mgrs

It should work in Windows in addition to your favorite unix scripting environment.