# MGRS in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinate-system, mgrs

I am trying to view the Military Grid Reference System coordinates in Openlayers through the MousePosition control. Is there an easy way to accomplish this just through Javascript? I am looking at the Proj4 library and I can't seem to find support for this.

Also, why can I not find an EPSG code for this reference system? Being relatively new to geospatial web development, the answers I am finding online are just sending me in circles.

Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use U.S. National Grid functions. add this [code](http://www.koders.com/javascript/fid8BFB11FBBD0AEE3514D27417DC02B99602B01837.aspx?s=sha1) to your index page

```
<script src=”usng.js” mce_src=”usng.js”></script>
```

and then run this method:

> 1.LLtoUSNG(lat, lon, precision) : convert lat/lng decimal degrees to a USNG string

example:

```
alert(LLtoUSNG(lat, long, 5));
```

example result:

```
Five digits:  1 meter precision    eg. "18S UJ 23480 06470"
```

> 2.USNGtoLL(usng_string,latlng) : convert a USNG string to lat/lng decimal degrees

example input:

```
NNCCCNNNNNNNNNN
NNC CC NNNNNNNNNN
NNC CC NNNNN NNNNN
```

> 3.LLtoUTM(lat,lon, utmcoords): Converts lat/long to UTM coords.

there are some informations in js...

As for the other question, mgrs system is not a coordinate tuple because of having four parameters. in normal case coordinate tuples consist of two parameter as lat and lon...

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Bastion of knowledge [wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USNG#Overview) "_It resembles the Military Grid Reference System (MGRS). When the WGS84 datum or NAD83 datum is used, USNG and MGRS coordinates are practically identical._"  The question, I think, is how are they not precisely identical?  Possibly also worth pointing out that the lib linked in this answer is GPL'd.

Comment: Looks like you can get that answer [here](http://www.amerisurv.com/PDF/TheAmericanSurveyor_USNationalGrid-Cavell_June2005.pdf). For NAD 83 or WGS 94, they produce "equivalent" values. In NAD 27, there's a difference, apparently.

Comment: @Aragon link to library is dead. Do you have a copy of it to share please?

Comment: https://github.com/codice/usng.js